# HTML file is not loading in browser

Tags: javascript, html

newbie here, I can't seem to load my html file on any browser, pls help?

I followed the instructions from Head First Javascript Programming from O'Reilly and am trying to open my file 'behavior.html' on my browser. Isn't working on Chrome, Safari or Firefox. I've tried changing the `<!doctype html>` with just `<html>`but the result is the same. What is supposed to happen does not happen. Here is an image of what comes up:
[browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsK6h.png).

The code is

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=“en”>

    <head>

        <meta charset=“utf-8”>

        <title>Just a Generic Page hola</title>

        <script>

            setTimeout(wakeUpUser, 5000);

            function wakeUpUser() {

                alert(“Are you going to stare at this page forever??????????”);

            }

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>This is called a heading</h1>

        <p>Not all too much to read here. I’m a paragraph from a JS book and Tony’s mind.</p>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I did not use the ``` in the actual script but could not get the <!doctype html> to show otherwise.

Comment: Regarding the syntax for code highlightiing here on SO, you have to start a new line after the ``` syntax.

Comment: Wherever you got this code from is using invalid quote marks.  Use regular quote marks, not "smart" quotes.

Comment: Have you tried the page without the `<script>` content?  Assuming the page has been saved with a .html extension the rest is about as basic as it gets so should load fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `“` with `"`, and remove that ``` at the beginning
avoid to copy paste formatted source code, you should write it or paste without format.

Comment: While this *is* an issue with the document, it can't be the cause of the problem the OP is experiencing.

Comment: This made the difference, ty!!

Answer (score 0):

While there are lots of problems with that HTML, the core issue is that the browser doesn't think it is HTML.

Since you are loading it from a file path (and not an HTTP(S) URL) this will be because you gave it a file extension that is not `.html` (although whatever you did use is cut-off in the screenshot). Possibly you have `behaviour.html.txt` or similar.

Rename the file.

You should probably also change your editor (e.g. to Visual Studio Code). Whatever you are using is probably responsible for your use of `“` and `”` where you need `"` and the wrong file extension.

Comment: Got it, will do! didn't know there were different types of quotes..

Answer (score -2):

Is it possible that you need to write `<!DOCTYPE html>` in capitals?

Comment: No. The use of ALL CAPS for the word DOCTYPE is a convention only.